# Futurebuilder does not properly display data

Tags: flutter

I'm facing with an error right now. The data comes properly but Futurebuilder shows blank widget instead of a ListView.builder(). After rebuilding the same page by clicking the same bottomnavbar widget, it shows the data properly. [Here is my Yt video](https://youtu.be/bRoCUydVB4U) demonstration of the error and here is my code:

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: favoritesFuture,
              builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: list.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 16.0),
                            child: FavoritesContainer(
                              product: list[index],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                }
              }),
            )
```

Rest of the stateful widget:

```
  late List<Product> list;
  late Future favoritesFuture;
  Future<List<Product>> getFavorites() async {
    var repo = FavoritesRepository();
    await repo.init();
    list = await repo.getFavoriteProducts();
    setState(() {});
    return list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    favoritesFuture = getFavorites();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: You might be using functional component instead a proper widget. Please more code.

Comment: Are you awaiting the Future?

Comment: I solved it. I was using forEach to make some calculations but forEach does not work async so I changed it to Future.forEach and made it work.

Comment: OT: May I ask you how did you manage to put a bottom Navigationbar that is not affected by change of screen's animation?

Comment: @Dani3le_ Bottom navigation bar holds the widgets seperately and animations are backed by their own statefulwidgets. I just made them apart. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: I’m also using transition library.

Comment: That's what I was asking, yes. I didn't fully understand how you did it; have you got any links "how-to"?

Comment: @Dani3le_ If you can share your e-mail, I can send a copy of my code with parts you  asking for.

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş That would be great. Thank you very much. (`d.aniel3@yandex.com`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

The problem is, inside favorites_repository, I used a forEach for calculating other things related to List of Products. And I noticed that **forEach DOES NOT APPLY AWAIT**. So you **can't run asynchronous forEach** methods on anywhere. So I used this method to make it work:

````
    Iterable l = json.decode(response.body);
    List<Product> list = [];
    await Future.forEach(l, (element) async {
      var model = FavoriteProduct.fromMap(element as Map<String, dynamic>);
      var product = await repo.getProductById(model.urunId);
      list.add(product);
    });

    if (list.isNotEmpty) {
      return list;
    } else {
      return [];
    }```

Just use Future.forEach and you are good to go. It did work now.
````